# Black screen with cursor booting after trying to install AMDGPU drivers

Tags: drivers

In an attempt to improve performance of the gpu on my new laptop, I tried to install it via these directions: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=272074

I was able to get the install to happen (although there was an error message that I didn’t pay close attention to when the operation had completed) and rebooted, as the instructions on the AMD site say to do.

When I rebooted, the Linux Mint splash logo showed up and then all that was displayed was a black screen with a blinking cursor. I can use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to log in to a terminal, but that’s it.

It seems there are a ton of broken packages that didn’t fully install when I run a dpkg audit. I’m guessing that Mint is trying to use the new drivers but is running into errors because the new drivers didn’t actually install. Any thoughts or help on how to fix this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by logging into the terminal and running sudo aptitude. Inside there I used the “g” option which allows you to remove packages and it was able to remove everything that was not satisfied by dependencies.

What a pain. But so grateful I didn’t have to reinstall Linux mint all over again.